# Finding location of all references across solution

Tags: c#, roslyn, projects-and-solutions, roslyn-code-analysis, find-all-references

I'm trying to find all references for all types across a solution using `Roslyn API`.

Sure enough, I do get references to the types (using `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync`), but when I check for their location (using `SymbolFinder.FindSourceDefinitionAsync`) I get a `null` result.

**What Have I tried so far?**

I am loading the solution using:
`this._solution = _msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;`

and getting the references using:

```
List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> solutionTypes = this.GetSolutionClassDeclarations();

var res = solutionTypes.ToDictionary(t => t,
                              t =>
                              {
                                  var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", new SyntaxTree[] { t.SyntaxTree }, new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) });
                                  var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(t.SyntaxTree);
                                  var classSymbols = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(t);

                                  var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(classSymbols, this._solution).Result;
                                  foreach (var r in references)
                                  {
                                        //=== loc is allways null... ===
                                      var loc = SymbolFinder.FindSourceDefinitionAsync(r.Definition, this._solution).Result;
                                  }

                                  return references.ToList();
                              });
```

But as I said, all references has no locations.

[image: Null location]

When I look for all references in VS (2015) - I do get the references.

[image]

---

**Update:**

Following up on @Slacks advice I have fixed the code and it is now working properly. I'm posting it here for future reference for the googlers...

```
    Dictionary<Project, List<ClassDeclarationSyntax>> solutionTypes = this.GetSolutionClassDeclarations();

    var res = new Dictionary<ClassDeclarationSyntax, List<ReferencedSymbol>>();
    foreach (var pair in solutionTypes)
    {
        Project proj = pair.Key;
        List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> types = pair.Value;
        var compilation = proj.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
        foreach (var t in types)
        { 
            var references = new List<ReferencedSymbol>();

            var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(t.SyntaxTree);
            var classSymbols = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(t);

            references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(classSymbols, this._solution).Result.ToList();

            res[t] = references;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `Compilation` with only that source file and no relevant references.  Therefore, the symbol in that compilation won't work, and certainly won't be bound to anything in your existing `Solution`.

You need to get the `Compilation` from the `Project` containing the node.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'll give it a try. I suspected it was due to creating the compilation from the type's syntax tree.  If understand what you are saying, I need to change the compilation creation to: `var compilation  = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;` right?

Comment: Yes, except that you should call that just once, outside your loop, and `await` it.

Comment: Will this also give me cross-project references locations?

Comment: @AviTurner: Yes; that's why it takes a `Solution`.